# What is a good reference for learning/improving proof writing?

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, education

I study in the field of theoretical computer science in which i try to find new methods or improve old methods based on mathematical principles.
So, often when i try to publish the work i need to write theorems/lemmas and also their proofs in a proper mathematical way!

Therefore, i'm looking for a good reference/guide to improve my proof writing skills. I googled it, but there are a lot of resources and not sure which ones are best to try.

Comment: Some refs: Joseph Rotman, [Journey into Mathematics : An Introduction to Proofs](https://books.google.it/books?id=6QDCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Dover (1998) and Antonella Cupillari, [The Nuts and Bolts of Proofs](https://books.google.it/books?id=WDdd9LQBWCgC&printsec=frontcover), Elsevier (4th ed).

Comment: The book [_How To Prove It_](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.amazon.co.uk/How-Prove-Structured-Daniel-Velleman/dp/0521675995&ved=2ahUKEwixwfa4hMncAhXKB8AKHeEnCqEQFjALegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2pl5pBwHp1P2DqEIzDe9zH) by Daniel Velleman helped me great deal.

Comment: The paper [The notational conventions I adopted, and why](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html) by Edsger W. Dijkstra has been helpful for me.

Comment: "Mathematical Writing" by Knuth, Larrabee and Roberts contains notes from a course on mathematical writing taught at Stanford.  The link below is for a pdf copy, or you can buy a hard  copy from Amazon.  http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf

Comment: @Bob: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190981/how-to-be-good-at-proving/190987, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289131/how-do-you-rebuild-your-math-skills-after-college?lq=1

Comment: See also: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1806/1806.06892.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)