# Book covering introduction to mathematical proofs

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, axioms

I am looking for some introductory books covering mathematical proofs, axioms, propositions, proof techniques etc in general.

Comment: See my answer here - first several books: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190981/how-to-be-good-at-proving, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289131/how-do-you-rebuild-your-math-skills-after-college?lq=1

Comment: A good book I learned from is "Write Your Own Proofs," by Amy Babich and Laura Person.

Comment: From my point of view, the best way to learn how to do proofs is to well... see and do them. It is very much like your first rigorous mathematics textbook, you get started by opening the cover. I would say Spivak's "Calculus" serves as a good introduction (softer than let's say Rudin which would be intractable for most students uninitiated into proofs) to both analysis and proofs at the same time; this would probably be a good starting point, perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expanding problem solving skill](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187340/expanding-problem-solving-skill)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic book about mathematical proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38854/basic-book-about-mathematical-proofs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out "Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics by Gary Chartrand, Albert Polimeni, and Ping Zhang". It is a great introduction to proof writing. The presentation is friendly  and it contains lots of problems to work on. Another great book of this type is "Book of Proof by Richard Hammack". Check out this link to view the entire book http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/. You could also check out "How to Prove it: A Structured Approach by Daniel Velleman", "Mathematical Reasoning: Writing and Proof by Ted Sundstrom", and "Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics by Ethan Bloch. All of these books are worth checking out when learning the basics.